# Git merge from branch to master: how to get clean master without branch stuff?

Tags: git

Here is my situation, there is a GIT repository, I am working on master while someone else is working on a branch, say subway, with the following history (say for one single file):

edit:sorry the formatting is not user-friendly, I've updated it as below:

Person A and B are both working on the same file, Person A is working on master with
commits:
Time1A, Time2A and Time3A
changes:
added 1, 3, 5 respectively

Person B is working on branch subway with commits:
Time1B, Time2B and Time3B
changes:
added 2, 4, 6 respectively

When PersonB merges from subway to master, the commits history will look like:

Time1A, Time1B, Time2A, Time2B, Time3A, Time3B

and in the file I got: 1,2,3,4,5,6.

If I need to get a clean master before the merge, can I just checkout the commit for Time3A? Does it include stuff merged from subway before Time3?

Thanks

Comment: Something didn't come through in your formatting, I think.  Can you clean it up and clarify your question?

Comment: What do you mean by a "clean" master here? Please clarify

Comment: @positron Hi I meant a master with only Person A's commits without any commits merged by person B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One better solution would be for B to rebase his/her work on A

```
(master) -> ... Time1A -- Time2A -- Time3A
                                        \
                                         >--  Time1B' -- Time2B' -- Time3B' (subway)
```

Then the merge to master is a fast-forward one:

```
(master) -> ... Time1A -- Time2A -- Time3A --  Time1B' -- Time2B' -- Time3B' (master,subway)
```

See "[`git rebase` vs `git merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178)".

Answer (score 3):

Making a merge in Git only adds to history. It does not modify the past — if you check out a past commit after a merge, that commit will be exactly as it was when that commit was made.

Incidentally, your timeline is not really correct: the two branches are not retroactively commingled like that. A better depiction of the commit history would be:

```
master -> ... Time1A -- Time2A -- Time3A
                                        \
                                         >-- Merge
                                        /
subway -> ... Time1B -- Time2B -- Time3B
```

In this history, the commit marked "Merge" has two parents (Time3A and Time3B).

Comment: But if Person B merges to master, then in the master's commit history, do I get all commits from Person A, followed by commits from Person B, or mixture of their commits?

Comment: You'd get all the parent commits, sorted by the time they were made. So, probably a mixture.

Comment: Yes, so I need to checkout a commit in master with only Person A's commits, that's what my question is asking, sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Checking out any one of those intermediate commits will still give you the contents that were originally part of that commit. Like I said, merging does not alter the past.

Comment: Yes, but the actual time line looks like A1, B1, A2, B2, B* are just in another branch before the merge.

Comment: It's still possible to tease them apart. `git log` will display them all together, but other tools will display something resembling the structure shown in my answer.